# Cache-control header doesn't work for IE11

Tags: internet-explorer, caching, internet-explorer-11, browser-cache, cache-control

Can someone explain me behaviour of IE11?

As I got, all browsers which support Http 1.1 (except some versions with bugs), have support of `Cache-Control` header.

I have backend which has `Access-Control-Request-Headers` with `Cache-Control` and `If-Modified-Since` only, so I can't use `Expires` or `Pragma`.
In my case, IE11 has strange behaviour.

Any directives of `Cache-Control` not work for me at all in IE11. IE11 just cache all requests with such headers:

- `Cache-Control: no-cache`
- `Cache-Control: no-store, no-cache`
- `Cache-Control: no-cache, max-age=0`
- `Cache-Control: no-store, no-cache, max-age=0, must-revalidate`
- and any other combinations of directives.

Interesting fact that just adding `If-Modified-Since: 0` solves my issue.

Why IE11 (I tried it on many PC) ignores `Cache-Control` at all and just caches all data?

Request's Headers:

```
   Accept: */*
   Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate
   Access-Control-Request-Headers: cache-control, expires, accept-language, x-website-token, authorization, x-website-config, accept
   Access-Control-Request-Method: GET
   Cache-Control: no-cache
   Content-Length: 0
   Host: ----
   Origin: ----
   User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; WOW64; Trident/7.0; rv:11.0) like Gecko
```

Response's Headers:

```
   access-control-allow-credentials: false
   access-control-allow-headers: DNT, User-Agent, X-Website-Token, X-Website-Config, X-Website-Dgp, X-Integration-Id, X-Requested-With, If-Modified-Since, Cache-Control, Content-Type,Range, Accept, Accept-Language, Authorization, DNT
   access-control-allow-methods: GET, POST, PUT, PATCH, DELETE, OPTIONS
   access-control-allow-origin: *
   access-control-expose-headers: X-Pagination-Total-Count, X-Pagination-Page-Count, X-Pagination-Current-Page, X-Pagination-Per-Page
   access-control-max-age: 3600
   content-type: application/json; charset=UTF-8
   date: Sat, 13 Jun 2020 23:01:32 GMT
   server: nginx/1.16.1
   set-cookie: x-last-referrer=;Domain=-----;Path=/;
   x-release-version: 1
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, Internet Explorer supports the HTTP 1.1 Cache-Control header, which prevents all caching of a particular Web resource when the no-cache value is specified by an HTTP 1.1 server.

Second, the Cache-Control HTTP header holds directives (instructions) for caching in both **requests** and **responses**. **A given directive in a request does not mean the same directive should be in the response**.

So, to prevent cache the response resource, we could set the `cache-control: no-cache` in response and set the Expires to "-1". Another method, as you said, updates the page via a conditional If-Modified-Since request. More detail information, please check this article: [How to prevent caching in Internet Explorer](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/234067/how-to-prevent-caching-in-internet-explorer).

Comment: I've read this resource before. I thought that request-header set policy for response cache but it doesn't. Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0):

I found out that behaviour depends on header type.

If I use `cache-control` as **request's header**, I have strange behaviour for all browsers. For example, chrome ignores all `cache-control` directives except of `no-cache` directive. When I use `no-cache` directive, chrome doesn't cache request. IE just ignores all directives of `cache-control` if it's request's header.
So, request's header is used for the intermediate proxies but hasn't any connections to response's cache.

But if I use cache-control as **response's header**, I have correct behaviour, any of the directives work as supposed to.

**In my case, I cannot change REST API and add `cache-control: no-cache` to responses as I haven't access rights. But I can say to revalidate cached response any time by using request's header `If-Modified-Sinse: 0`.**